# How get isolinux/isolinux.bin?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 15.04, backup

I want to make my own distribution of Ubuntu 15.04.

For this I used a program called `remastersys`. I did:

```
sudo remastersys dist cdfs 
sudo remastersys dist iso mydist.iso
```

after these commands I supposed my personal image of Ubuntu would be created, but the size of my image is only 36 kb.

I have this log:

```
Creating the iso file only
Distribution Mode Selected
Making disk compatible with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator.
Creating md5sum.txt for the livecd/dvd
Creating mydist.iso in /home/remastersys/remastersys
genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'isolinux/isolinux.bin' !
Creating mydist.iso.md5 in /home/remastersys/remastersys
/home/remastersys/remastersys/mydist.iso which is 36K in size is ready to be burned or tested in a virtual machine.
```

*How can I get a correct image?*

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with isolinux.bin but actually with how remastersys was checking for isolinux.bin, it doesn't exist with a parent directory "isolinux/isolinux.bin". Remastersys has since been abandoned by its original developer but we have adopted the project and renamed it `respin`. The updated code now works on Ubuntu 15.04 and even 16.04 but there seems to be a ubiquity issue in 16.04 that crashes when running the install of the custom iso which we are currently looking into. You can obtain the `respin` package from my launchpad ppa and install with the following commands:

*Please note this is the command line version. The python GTK gui version will be available soon.

For Ubuntu 15.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sergiomejia666/respin
```

Prese Enter to add repo

```
sudo apt-get-update

sudo apt-get install respin -y

sudo respin
```

For Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sergiomejia666/respin
```

Press Enter to add ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sergiomejia666/xresprobe
```

Press Enter to add ppa

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xresprobe -y

sudo apt-get install respin -y

sudo respin
```